# How to fix the stuck problem after the nni experiment start?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, automl

I have create a nni experiment by:

```
nnictl create --config config.yml
```

The content of config.yml file is:

```
maxExecDuration: 12h
maxTrialNum: 500
#choice: local, remote, pai
trainingServicePlatform: local
searchSpacePath: search_space.json
#choice: true, false
useAnnotation: false
multiThread: true
logDir: "/path/of/logdir/"
tuner:
  #choice: TPE, Random, Anneal, Evolution, BatchTuner, MetisTuner, GPTuner
  #SMAC (SMAC should be installed through nnictl)
  builtinTunerName: TPE
  classArgs:
    #choice: maximize, minimize
    optimize_mode: maximize
trial:
  command: python main.py
  codeDir: .
  gpuNum: 3
localConfig:
  gpuIndices: "1,2,3"
  maxTrialNumPerGpu: 4
  useActiveGpu: true
```

After a few minutes, the web interface of nni is stuck.
It shows nothing if I refresh the web interface.

I think maybe the problem is come up with `maxTrialNumPerGpu`, because I haven't gotten this problem when I haven't set `maxTrialNumPerGpu`.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: I run the experiment in the docker.

Comment: Ubuntu18.04, Nividia GeForce 3090